# a few questions on difference of gaussian

Tags: image-processing, signal-processing

I use this formula for DoG ([link](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csigma%7D%20%28%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E2%7D%7B2%5Csigma%5E2%7D-1.0%29%20e%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7B-x%5E2%7D%7B2%5Csigma%5E2%7D%7D)):

[image: another]

What is the relationship between this formula and the difference two Gaussian functions?

Can someone show me how to apply DoG on a 1D signal in Matlab? My input can be considered as a  1D real-valued function, and I applied the above formula to detect blobs. The results make sense except that I don't know why I get many local minimum in relatively flat region (i.e., function values at points in the region almost stay constant). Since I don't have enough signal processing/image processing background, I want to see what a constant signal look like after being convolved with a DoG filter.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, you have a better chance here: http://cs.stackexchange.com/ to get an answer to your question.

Comment: No - this is not a CS question - it's more of a DSP/maths question. It could stay here as it's about a MATLAB implementation, or it could go to http://dsp.stackexchange.com.

Comment: that formula is not DoG.  DoG is difference of two Gaussians of different sigma parameters.  To apply DoG filter in Matlab, first generate it into a vector (call it f, and your signal is s), then you can do *conv(f,s)* (or alternatively, use filter).